# Survival Regression using Stratification vs Partial Effects in Lifelines

Tags: survival, lifelines

I have been using the Lifelines survival estimation package: https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I am interested in the effect that a specific variable (number of pain sites) has on the survival model (using the CoxPH model). I tried introducing this model as a covariate using plot_partial_effects_on_outcome():
￼
[image: CoxPH Regression plotting partial effects]

and as a stratification variable:
￼
[image]

I am wondering if why these two methods present inverse survival ratings for the values of the variables? For example, 4 pain sites seems to decrease survival in the covariate model but increases survival in the stratification model, and the opposite for 1 pain site.

It is my understanding that the stratification method includes the variable in the model without estimating its effect. So would this be the same as plotting 4 different survival functions with different variable values? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: To be clear, you're not using "time" in the usual sense of survival - you're using something called Burden Score?

Comment: "I am wondering if why these two methods present inverse survival ratings for the values of the variables?"

Can you clarify this in your question (please edit the question)

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Yes, I am not using 'time' as in most survival analyses. I am evaluating the development of a condition based off of a subjects presentation (binned into percentiles) of a derived "burden score". As such, 3/4 of my observations are right-censored. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 1):

> It is my understanding that the stratification method includes the variable in the model without estimating its effect. So would this be the same as plotting 4 different survival functions with different variable values?

That's pretty close to what is going on, with one important note: there are other variables in the regression being accounted for. This may or may not have a large effect on the inference. It's up to you to decide if they should be included or not.